# how can I Reuse Networkstream[] ns = new NetworkStream[10] in the case of a client disconnecting

Tags: c#, arrays, type-conversion, initialization, syntax-error

I'm using Networkstream[] ns = new NetworkStream[10]; to hold the streams, one for each client.
when the client doesn't return a keepalive response the server runs the following code:

```
                        connectedClientsCount -= 1;
                        connectedClientsStreams[i].Dispose();
                        connectedClientsStreams[i] = new NetworkStream[i]; //Issue here
                        connectedClients[i].Close();
                        connectedClients[i] = new TcpClient(); //no issue
                            arrKeepAlive[i, 0] = 0;
                            arrKeepAlive[i, 1] = 0;
```

When trying to assign connectedClientsStreams[i] to a new networkstream instance I receive this error:
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream[]' to 'System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream

One of the answers suggests I initialize a new networkstream using parameters such as IPA and Port, this does not make logical sense to me in a client/server architecture. As a server will *never* have that information at hand.

A further description should prevent further misinterpretations.

The clients connect to the server, the server adds the connecting client sockets to the aforementioned array, the networkstreams are all initialized at runtime in a seperate array, the indexes from both arrays correlate towards each client, upon client disconnection the associated data for said client will be removed from both arrays, without reinitializing or refreshing the associated indexes a new client cannot use those indexes.

So my understanding is that I dispose of/close the existing networkstream and socket referenced in the 2 arrays, and then reinitialize them so that they are ready for any unknown future connections.

I already have a sense that Tom wants impersonal SE points instead of providing a solution/answer to a misinterpreted /poorly written question. I apologize for not being able to ask a question that caters to everyones understanding.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to create a new `NetWorkStream` instead of the one that was disposed, in your line that creates it with the `//Issue here` comment it should be the following:

```
connectedClientsCount -= 1;
connectedClientsStreams[i].Dispose();
connectedClientsStreams[i] = new NetworkStream(new Socket(...));  // initalize new object instead of array
connectedClients[i].Close();
connectedClients[i] = new TcpClient(); //no issue
arrKeepAlive[i, 0] = 0;
arrKeepAlive[i, 1] = 0;
```

The issue is with initializing a new array of `NetworkStream` instead of an object.

Comment: Hi Kshkarin, the server periodically loops through the array and pings each client expecting a response to ensure a connection still exists else the above code runs to remove the client from the server, the client tcpclient object exists in the one array, and that tcpclients stream exists in the other, i want to remove the old objects from their index in the respective arrays and prepare the indexes to be used again. So in your example it's expecting a new socket connection which may be handy for reconnecting but I dont believe it's applicable in preparing the indexes for future connections.

Comment: @JoseLiicksStuff the question was about assigning a new `NetworkStream` and resolving the exception, this is what the answer provides. if you have a new question for the next step then please open a new question, if this answer solved your original question then please accept it https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my query was the following:

```
connectedClientsCount -= 1;
connectedClientsStreams[i].Close(); //since close includes dispose
connectedClientsStreams[i] = null; //removes the closed NS reference
connectedClients[i].Close();
connectedClients[i] = new TcpClient(); //no issue
arrKeepAlive[i, 0] = 0;
arrKeepAlive[i, 1] = 0;
```

By setting the value at [i] index to null after closing, it allows me to reuse the network stream.